# Seeking tool to inspect/study monero cli source code

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I'm interested in digging in Monero CLI source code... not a specific reason for now, just hoping to get enough confidence to look at code as authoritative source of information when I have doubts.
I definitely should brush it up, but in the past I had experience with C/C++ and I still remember (or I think so ;) ) the bases... so my main problem now is to find something like a project inspector to be able to browse between Monero source components in a comfortable and ergonomic way (not only from a files perspective but also from a UML-like logical/interdependency of objects/functions point of view, with possibility to zoom in or out on project components, if possible)... Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems first answer is a selfish one ;) ... since yesterday I'm evaluating Sourcetrail (https://www.sourcetrail.com) and seems what I was seeking...

I haven't tried it against Monero source code yet, I've just followed the tutorial project introducing its main logic and functions.... but it seems what I'm looking for, so I'm writing about it hoping to help others with my same needs.

Of course I'll still be very happy to listen to other suggestions/experiences as well